# Disable nginx from using port 80

Tags: http, nginx, port, ip-address, restart

My nginx version 1.8 is installed under /etc/nginx

When i start nginx i get the below port Already in use error.

```
sudo systemctl start nginx
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
$ systemctl status nginx.service
● nginx.service - nginx - high performance web server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-11-27 06:24:18 UTC; 6s ago
     Docs: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
  Process: 24226 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 27 06:24:16 efendibey_live nginx[24226]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 27 06:24:16 efendibey_live nginx[24226]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 27 06:24:17 efendibey_live nginx[24226]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 27 06:24:17 efendibey_live nginx[24226]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 27 06:24:18 efendibey_live nginx[24226]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 27 06:24:18 efendibey_live nginx[24226]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
Nov 27 06:24:18 efendibey_live systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 27 06:24:18 efendibey_live systemd[1]: Failed to start nginx - high performance web server.
Nov 27 06:24:18 efendibey_live systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
Nov 27 06:24:18 efendibey_live systemd[1]: nginx.service failed.
$
```

I made sure there is no port 80 specified in nginx.conf or /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf. Infact, there is no port 80 in any file under the nginx home directory.

```
cd /etc/nginx
find . -name "*" | xargs grep 80
```

Output:

```
grep: .: Is a directory
grep: ./conf.d: Is a directory
grep: ./default.d: Is a directory
grep: ./certs: Is a directory
grep: ./modules: Is a directory
./conf.d/default.conf:    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
./certs/efendibey.de_privatekey.txt:Lm4er4hrt7PhgBir4DWC/bDOIIlhPdXWCr80v2V9hFdTc0CxDA39/ILl054Jjp4L
./certs/ca_bundle.crt:2SAeepyImJ2CzB80YG7WxlynHqNhpE7xfC7PzQlLgmfEHdU+tHFeQazRQnrFkW2W
./nginx.conf:        listen       [::]:7080 ipv6only=on default_server;
./win-utf:    82  E2809A ; # single low-9 quotation mark
./win-utf:    84  E2809E ; # double low-9 quotation mark
./win-utf:    85  E280A6 ; # ellipsis
./win-utf:    86  E280A0 ; # dagger
./win-utf:    87  E280A1 ; # double dagger
./win-utf:    89  E280B0 ; # per mille
./win-utf:    91  E28098 ; # left single quotation mark
./win-utf:    92  E28099 ; # right single quotation mark
./win-utf:    93  E2809C ; # left double quotation mark
./win-utf:    94  E2809D ; # right double quotation mark
./win-utf:    95  E280A2 ; # bullet
./win-utf:    96  E28093 ; # en dash
./win-utf:    97  E28094 ; # em dash
./win-utf:    F0  D180 ;   # small r
./koi-utf:    80  E282AC ; # euro
./koi-utf:    95  E280A2 ; # bullet
./koi-utf:    D2  D180 ;   # small r
./koi-win:    80  88 ; # euro
```

Also,

```
$ grep server *.* conf.d/*.*
grep: conf.d: Is a directory
grep: default.d: Is a directory
nginx.conf:    server {
nginx.conf:        listen       [::]:7080 ipv6only=on default_server;
nginx.conf:        server_name 199.247.23.57;
nginx.conf:    server {
nginx.conf:#    server_name efendibey.de; # managed by Certbot
nginx.conf:    server_name 199.247.23.57
conf.d/default.conf:server {
conf.d/default.conf:    server_name  localhost;
conf.d/default.conf:    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
conf.d/default.conf:    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
```

When i free port 80 nginx is able to start successfully.

Can you please suggest why and where is nginx picking the port 80 from ?

Comment: assuming you using linux of some sort, netstat -tulpn can get u the processes running. You see which process is on port 80.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly specify the listening port in **all** your `server` blocks of nginx configuration (you can check all the included files with the `nginx -T` command), because as `listen` directive documentation [states](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen):

> If the directive is not present then either `*:80` is used if nginx runs with the superuser privileges, or `*:8000` otherwise.

Comment: Rightly said, one of the `server` directives was missing `listen` entry which was defaulting it to use port `80`. Many thanks!!